# Change min password length

Tags: magento2, password

I am making users programmatically (weird system that a company wants, where users send their details to company's email, they then create user in their CRM, and upload users data to server, where I pick it up and create user from it), and the problem is, that password shorter than 6 characters are not allowed. I've updated this in administration, and that seems to only work when users register in the frontend.

How can I set minimum password length for users I am making in the backend?

Example of code that creates user:

```
    $CustomerModel = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer');


    $CustomerModel->setWebsiteId(1); 
    $CustomerModel->loadByEmail($email);

    if (!$CustomerModel->getId()) {
        $customer = $customerFactory->create();
        $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);

        $customer->setEmail($email);
        $customer->setFirstname($name);
        $customer->setPassword($password);
        $customer->save();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to :

> /vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Customer/Attribute/Backend/Password.php

```
const MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 6;
```

You can change password length from here.